# AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer: taking a snapshot

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, avfoundation

I'm trying to emulate the animation seen in the default camera app, where a snapshot of the cameras viewfinder is animated into the corner of the apps display.

The AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer object that holds the key to solving this problem isn't very open to these requirements: trying to create a copy of it in a new layer with ..

```
- (id)initWithLayer:(id)layer
```

.. returns an empty layer, without the image snapshot, so clearly there is some deeper magic going on here.

Your clues/boos are most welcome.

M.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

facing the same woes, from a slightly different angle.

Here are possible solutions, that none are too great IMO:

- You can add to an *AVCaptureSession* both an *AVCaptureStillImageOutput* and an *AVCaptureVideoDataOutput*. When you set the *sessionPreset* to *AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh* you'll start getting frames by the API, and when you switch to *AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto* you can take real images. So right before taking the picture, you can switch to video, get a frame, and then return to camera. Major caveat is that it takes a "long" time (couple of seconds) for the camera to switch between the video camera and picture camera.
- Another option would be to use only the camera output (*AVCaptureStillImageOutput*), and use *UIGetScreenImage* to get a screen capture of the phone. You could then crop out the controls and leave only the image. This gets complicated if you're showing UI controls over the image. Also, according to [this](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/user-interface/screen-capture-using-uigetscreenimage.html) post, Apple started rejecting apps that use this function (it was always iffy).
- Aside from these I also tried playing with *AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer*. There's [this](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2008/10/getting-contents-of-uiview-as-uiimage.html) post to save a UIView or CALayer to a UIImage. But it all produces clear or white images. I tried accessing the layer, the view's layer, the *superlayer*, the *presentationLayer*, the *modelLayer*, but to no avail. I guess the data in *AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer* is very internal, and not really part of the regular layer infrastructure.

Hope this helps,
Oded.

Comment: which one is better @Oded Ben Dov in the above three. Give the best suggestion\

Answer (score 5):

I think you should add an `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` to the current session with:

```
AVCaptureVideoDataOutput *videoOutput = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init];
videoOutput.videoSettings = @{ (NSString *)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey : @(kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA) };
[session addOutput:videoOutput];

dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("MyQueue", NULL);
[videoOutput setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:queue];
dispatch_release(queue);
```

Then, implement the delegate method below to get your image snapshot:

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection {

    UIImage *image = [self imageFromSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer];
    // Add your code here that uses the image.
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        _imageView.image = image;
    });   
}
```

This will consume memory and reduce the performance of the app. To improve, you can also optimize your `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` with:

```
videoOutput.minFrameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 15);
```

You can also use `alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames`.

Comment: Small note: `alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames` is `true` by default

Answer (score 0):

there are 2 ways to grab frames of the preview.. AVCaptureVideoDataOutput & AVCaptureStillImageOutput :)

is your capture session is setup to grab video frames, then make your layer with the cgimage from a chosen frame. if it's setup for stills, wait until getting your still image and make your layer from a scaled down version of that cgimage. if you don't have an output on your session yet, you'll have to add one i think.

Answer (score -7):

Starting in iOS 7, you can use [UIView::snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:) to snapshot the UIView wrapping your AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer. This is not the same as `UIGetScreenImage`, which will get your app rejected.

```
UIView *snapshot = [self.containerView snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:YES];
```

Recall the old-school way of turning a view into an image. For some reason it worked on everything except for camera previews:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.containerView.bounds.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
[self.containerView drawViewHierarchyInRect:self.containerView.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates: does not work on AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer.

Comment: Very annoying that this was posted, it does not work on an AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer, just wasted time