# Display live video streaming, but can not capture images by UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext?

Tags: iphone, image, avfoundation, capture

I use AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer to display the live video streaming, something like this:

```
AVCaptureSession *captureSession = yourcapturesession;
previewLayer = [AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer layerWithSession:captureSession];
UIView *aView = theViewYouWantTheLayerIn;
previewLayer.frame = aView.bounds;
[aView.layer addSublayer:previewLayer];
```

then I use this to capture the image. I get a UIImage object but the image is black:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.previewLayer.bounds.size);
[self.previewLayer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
NSLog("%@",image);
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: Please try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397899/avcapturevideopreviewlayer-taking-a-snapshot. Hope that help!

Answer (score 1):

Tried doing this too, w/ the same results - no image.

I think the answer is that it's just not doable because it's not really handing over the RGB image to the context, just "showing it through a viewport" or something similar, if that makes sense.